# How to do atomic operation on structures inside CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda

I have the below piece of code where I'm trying to increment the structure called SL. How can I atomically increment the same in the below case? How to avoid the race condition? I don't care about the parallelization achieved in this case.

```
__global__ void insertKernel(struct SlabList* head_ref, int* new_key, int* new_val, int size,struct SlabList* SL, struct SlabList* temp){
 int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        if(id<size/SLAB_SIZE){
        head_ref=NULL;
        struct SlabList* new_node = (struct SlabList*) 
        malloc(sizeof(struct SlabList));
        for(int j=0;j<SLAB_SIZE;j++){
               new_node->key[j] = new_key[id*SLAB_SIZE+j];
               new_node->val[j]= new_val[id*SLAB_SIZE+j];
        }
        new_node->next = head_ref;
        memcpy(SL,new_node, size * sizeof(struct SlabList));
        head_ref    = new_node;
        SL++;//How to perform this atomically?
}
```

I looked into `atomicInc` and `atomicAdd` APIs of CUDA but was not able to proceed as they take different parameters.

Comment: The code you show isn't trying to perform atomic operations on a structure, it is trying performing atomic operations on a pointer, which is trivial

Comment: `atomicAdd((unsigned long long *)&SL, sizeof(SL[0]));`  This assumes you are running on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Note also that the operations on `head_ref` are also a memory race and would need to be handled atomically for this code to have any chance of working correctly

Comment: After thinking about this for a while, I realized that my previous comment, while possibly "technically" correct, would probably not have the desired effect, because the `SL` pointer is a quantity that is populated to all threads separately.  It is not a "global" entity.  When one thread "updates" it, that would have no effect on other threads copy of `SL`.  The same will be true for `head_ref`.  This probably should be tackled using a different method, for example a grid-stride loop, where each thread can know a-priori which locations are reserved for it with no atomics.

Answer (score 1):

By my reckoning, there are two operations which would only work correctly if performed atomically (without changes to the structure of the code)-- the increment of `SL` which you highlight, and exchange of the `head_ref` pointer value as the tree expands.

If (and only if), you are using a 64 bit operating system, then something like this might work:

```
__global__ void insertKernel(struct SlabList* head_ref, int* new_key, 
                             int* new_val, int size, struct SlabList* SL, struct SlabList* temp)
{
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(id<size/SLAB_SIZE){
        struct SlabList* new_node = (struct SlabList*)malloc(sizeof(struct SlabList));
        SlabList* SLnew = (SlabList *)atomicAdd((unsigned long long *)&SL,
                                                sizeof(struct SlabList));
        SlabList* oldhead = (SlabList *)atomicExch((unsigned long long *)&head_ref, 
                                        (unsigned long long)new_node);
        for(int j=0;j<SLAB_SIZE;j++){
            new_node->key[j] = new_key[id*SLAB_SIZE+j];
            new_node->val[j] = new_val[id*SLAB_SIZE+j];
        }
        new_node->next = oldhead;
        memcpy(SLnew, new_node, sizeof(struct SlabList));
    }
}
```

[Note: never compiled or run, let alone tested. Use at own risk]